# What kind of regression should I run on data that looks like this (multiple lines in scatterplot)

Tags: regression, python, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn

I am sure my terminology is a bit off here, this is my first such analysis. I have a dataframe with quite a few columns, and I am trying to understand what are the major coefficients for a model that would describe it.

I am trying to figure out if the price of an item is outperforming or underperforming the average price for it. There are many descriptors, one of the descriptors is how large the item is. If it's larger, then the price per unit goes down. I tried plotting it and got these curves which seemed inverse:
[image]
price is y, size of unit is x

so I inverted the data so I could try to get some lines rather than curves:
[image]
Now Y is still price, i/size of unit is X

Now I have a dataframe with more columns than I'm using here, and am hoping to use those columns to figure out what are the major coefficients in a model that could describe this. How should I model this? It's not purely a linear model, line y=AX+B, there's obviously some other factor that makes those lines. It's got to be like y=(some coefficient + A)X + B, etc?

If it helps, I'm using pandas in python, and am hoping to solve this with scikit learn, though I'm open to anything in python.

Appreciate the help

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. It turns out that the prices tended to be along certain values as they are sold by people. So like burgers tend to be 6.99 with variance in size and toppings, so was this. This made for horizontal lines in the unit/price graph. Divided by, say, pounds of beef (where there is a bit of variance per burger), you'd still get lines, but they would be inverse like the first graph, and then divide that by the inverse and you'd get sloping lines like the second graph. I still am uncertain how to figure out the coefficients for the other columns, but will update with the solve